# DIY Servo arm using wrong inverse kinematics doesn't make a straight line

Tags: arduino, robotics, servo

I have built a Servo-Arms with HS-422 servo (super simple basic servo motors found in a starter kit) that gets angle values with inverse kinematics in Processing (java).

The inverse kinematic (on computer) is ok and it is based on [this](http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=553)

The communication with arduino is ok, in the sense that if I put the 2 servos at 0°-0°, 90°-90°, 180°-180° the arms go in the right position.

BUT if I draw a straight line in my java sketches... the 2servo-arms draw.. a kind of weird 'U'.

Code of Inverse kinematics is [here](https://github.com/nkint/TwoServoArm/blob/master/TwoServoArm_PROCESSING/TwoServoArm_PROCESSING.pde).

But I think it is right and there is some structural-mechanic problem I can't understand.
Someone can advice me something?

## EDIT:

resolved! there were some problems, caused by wrong inverse kinematic. both comment and answer was usefull, thanks to this powerful community!

Comment: Perhaps: I assume you will have trie 0, 90, 180, 270 degree line drawing. 
| Try drawing 45, 135, 225, 315 degree line forwards and backwards and see what results are symmetric and which assymetric. eg if a component has the wrong sign you may find that in some quadrants the result curves to the left and in others to the right. Making arms to be equal length (they may or may not be) simplifies changes which may affect things.  I had a quick look through your code but nothing obvious. Can you simplify actions / code  to remove possible error sources.

Comment: thanks for comment! i'm trying to simply stuffs. by the way my servo are only between 0°-180° !

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the servo velocity is not being properly controlled.

Can you slow the arm movement down?

Remember, for inverse kinematics to work properly, you need very precise control of the rate of rotation. If your system has the arm moving from one point to another at the maximum possible velocity, the servos may be hitting their maximum rotation speed. As such, one servo would complete its motion before the other, which would turn your line into a series of arc segments, that are partially blended together.

Try controlling the system so the arm moves to points in an X-Y coordinate system. If the arm can correctly move the pen to the specified points, it's a servo-speed issue. If not, it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's almost impossible to ensure that any two servos will move at exactly the same speed, the simple, catch-all solution would be to generate a trajectory for your end effector (X,Y) coordinates. So, for example, if you want to draw a straight line, simply create a linear trajectory of the form y= mx + b (should be familiar to most of you). Just make the x a function of time by putting " x = t; t++; " at the end of the loop. You do need to have a fixed loop time, of course - if you don't need to be doing anything else during the movement, simply use a while loop that terminates when the desired coordinates are reached. Another advantage of this method is that you can vary the speed at which it draws the line; for instance, rather than " t++ " you can put " t += 0.7 " for a slower speed.